# Pseudosemantic question

Tags: verbs, lexical-semantics

Forgive me if this isn't right place to ask this kind od question, which I'm aware is not, but at the same time I can't pick any more adequate from the list of SE sites.

Premise is this: Verb [x] in a single specific form - in particular tense, person, number, gender... - is independent lexical unit, independent from the original verb; it has it's own special meaning, and, unlike other verbs, it's invariable.
Premise is arbitrary and unscientific; I'm going to use it as a literary device. I have a strong feeling it isn't my original idea, and I'd like to know history of "it", terminology of "it" specially.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you give a few examples? There are plenty of verbs where a specific form of a verb can have an idiomatic meaning that other forms cannot, at least in English and many other languages. E.g. *gone* does not have a passive meaning like almost all other past participles. But I'm not sure whether that is what you mean.

Comment: It's totally liberal construct: you can take any verb and argue that its specific form is so special it makes lexical entity for itself, and support it by connecting each gramatic element to some indispensable part of the word meaning.
I have a specific verb in mind, but really every verb can fit, and it's not in English besides.

Comment: OK, this should make it clear. - It's pretty much ordinary verb; but, in specific case, its specific form moves away from original meaning (of the o. verb in infinitive and it's whole 'family') and takes characteristics of a phrase. Pair in question, translated, is fall-fell. Fell descripts event of criminal getting caught, usually drug dealer or drug smuggler, and it's common expression in Crimes & Courts sections of the news. Like busted, but not exactly. - How long it took to just define the problem! If you can explain it further, or recommend what to read on topic, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: If I understood you correctly your are talking about semantic change - have a look at the relevant [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change). Whether you are talking about a verb or noun etc. does not, in most cases, make much of a difference.

Comment: @robert There's no such historical shift here like in the examples from the article, but helpful enough.

Comment: You seem to be asking about the case where one particular form in a paradigm comes to have specific semantics that differ markedly from those of the other forms in the paradigm, is that right? An example would be 'hanged', which refers only to a person, whereas all other forms of the verb 'hang' have broader semantics.

Comment: Thanks Gaston, very close. Is there some more synthetic definition, if not single-word term for that phenomenon?

Comment: I don't know of a specific term, but doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: Basically it's just an idiom? It has a distinct meaning and is more restricted in what inflections it allows.

Comment: Can you please put an actual example or two of what you're talking about in the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

*Correct me if I misunderstood your question.* Assuming that you refer to a fixed combination of morphemes, e.g., fixed root, derivational morphemes, and inflectional morphemes, just as in German `nimmst ... mit` (as a 2nd person singular present indicative form of `mitnehmen` lexeme).

What you are talking about seems to be simply `word`, [morphologically unparsed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_parsing), or `word form`.
Specifically answering your question, whether `word` is:

- *an independent lexical unit, independent from the original verb* — **No**:

  - not a lexical unit, since [Lexicon deals with Lexemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicon#Size_and_organization), not with individual word forms;
  - not an independent one. If you define "independent" is that you can *use* it independently, you really can do it in only a tiny subset of sentences that require only this particular word form;
- *it has it's own special meaning* — **One or many**, indistinguishable if you *really* analyze the word alone;

  - Consider English `works` — it can be either a noun (in plural form), a verb (3rd person singular), or a family name (a proper noun). Even if you stick to verbs, I believe it's easy to find counter-examples in virtually every language;
- *and, unlike other verbs, it's invariable* — **Yes**, it's invariable. However, how can we compare a whole lexeme (a complete set of its forms) and one of its particular word forms?

Comment: It's from Bosnian/Serbian/Croatian language, which is, I guess, very inflected. In compare to English, at least.
*Pasti* is infinitive (perfective aspect), and *pao* its 3rd person past tense (not that relevant, but in its truncated form, without aux. verb `to be`). In that form, in context described in comment^, it's part of special phrase; and in **that** meaning, it can take no other form: no other person, tense or aspect, neither you can make nouns or adverbs out of it or *name* it by reverting to original lexem's family. My case for separating it, aniway. Along with artistic freedom;)

Comment: That's rather like the use of fronted counterfactual _were_ clauses in English: _Were it the case that English was polysynthetic..._ Only the verb form _were_ may be used here, and it has a special meaning. It's common enough for individual words to have special idiomatic contexts where they're frozen for grammatical purposes.